# Quotient of direct sum of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $A \oplus B \simeq A' \oplus B $. Does it follow that $A\simeq A'$? 
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your second question is equivalent to the first one.

Comment: This question has been asked at least $10$ times on math.SE.

Comment: They are equivalent, because $B \cong B'$ implies $A' \oplus B' \cong A' \oplus B$. Your question is not about equality.

Comment: can you give the link? Thank you)

Comment: @helen: For a good link follow the [Cancellation Theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255629649) and on.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg omg, of course they were equivalent..Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the one-element group, and $A'=\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $B$ the direct sum of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: A' can be arbitrary non-zero.

Comment: @André Nicolas: but is there simple reasonable  explanation in case of finite groups?

Comment: @helen:  For finite (or finitely generated) Abelian groups, the Fundamental Theorem gives us cancellation. For finite groups in general, and more,  there is the Krull-Schmidt Theorem, quite a bit harder.